# How to pass data from regular stateless servlet to backend instance?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, backend

I've never used Google App Engine backends and I'm very confused by lack of samples and detailed documentation.

Let's say I have a voting app. I want to collect votes in regular stateless GAE servlet and then pass the data to backend instance that is resident and it processes my data. How can I pass data from regular servlet to backend servlet ? How do I assign what servlet class is normal servlet and what servlet should be handled only in backend instance? I don't see how I can assign servlet to backend in config xml.

Or what if I have two backends - class B1 and class B2. How can I choose in code of stateless servlet what backends are active right now? I heard that I should use URL Fetch to talk to backends but how ? I didn't find how I can iterate through backend instances.

Please advise :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start by reading [the documentation on backends](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview.html)

> How can I pass data from regular servlet to backend servlet ?

You have a few options - pass it indirectly by sticking data in memcache or the datastore.  Or pass it directly by using URLFetch to make requests to your backends (see addressing info below)

> How do I assign what servlet class is normal servlet and what servlet should be handled only in backend instance?

The doc on [Backend Configuration](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/backends.html) explains that you can't do that (yet), though you can mark them as admin only so they are not available to the public:

> Backends share the set of servlets defined in web.xml with your main application version. It is not possible at the moment to configure a separate set of servlets for each backend.

The "Addressing Backends" section includes info on how to connect to a specific backend:

> A backend instance can be targeted with HTTP requests to http://[instance].[backend].[app].appspot.com, or at your application's custom domain. If you target a backend without targeting an instance using http://[backend].[app].appspot.com, App Engine selects the first available instance of the backend.

When you configure your backends , you give them names, which go into the [backend] slot in the url scheme described above.  If you wanted to send a http request to the first available B1 instance, you would use something like *http://B1.ruslansapp.appspot.com/dosomething/*

Comment: There's an API for getting the URL for a backend in a manner that works across dev and production and avoids the need to hardcode URLs: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/backends/package-summary.html

Comment: @NickJohnson and Peter, do you know by any chance if there is way to find out amount of active instances per given backend ? I don't see anything like that in API. What I'd like to do is to use dynamic instances and load-balance calls to them in frontend-servlet. According to documentation Google may change amount of instances based on the load. On the other had using constant amount of resident instances is pretty expensive.

Comment: It is my understanding that you shouldn't need to manually load balance the backends.  As long as you don't specify a specific instance, app engine will send  your request to the next available backend.

Comment: Well, to me the benefit of backend instance versus frontend stateless instance is that it allows me to keep something in the memory for longer than 10 sec period :)

Comment: @NickJohnson, quick question to you. Does `com.google.appengine.api.backends.BackendService.getBackendAddress()` return different addresses when more than one dynamic instance set in config ? In development environment it always returns IP:port of the same instance.