# GoogleAppEngine Backends

Tags: java, google-app-engine, backend

How can I create a backend?

The GAE teaches how to configure, but there is no line showing how define the java class that will be called or what request will be done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/backends.html):

> Backends share the set of servlets defined in web.xml with your main
>   application version. It is not possible at the moment to configure a
>   separate set of servlets for each backend.

Backends run all the same servlets that your front end does.  It is up to you to call the appropriate URLs for whatever tasks you need performed.

For example, if you want your backend to calculate all the prime numbers from 1 to a million, you would create a servlet that uses your GeneratePrimeNumber class, and have that servlet configured to respond to requests to some url, like myapp.appspot.com/calculatePrimes.  You would then need to call that URL to make your backend do the work.  You could call it from a frontend instance, you could call it from a task in the task queue, or you could call it from a cron job.

See [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923129/how-to-pass-data-from-regular-stateless-servlet-to-backend-instance) for more answers to basic back end issues.